# expected number of cards drawn exactly once (with replacement)

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

> Suppose there are $N$ cards, $1,2,\dots,N$.
>   We start drawing cards (with replacement), until each card has been drawn at least once (we stop when the last card is drawn for the first time).
>   Let $x$ be the number of cards that have been drawn exactly once.
>   What is the expected value of $x$?

The answer is supposed to be $1 + \frac{1}{2} +\dots+ \frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at calculating $E(x)$? where $x$ is the number of cards that have been drawn exactly once? Did you attempt at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card $c_k$ that is drawn as the $k$-th last has a probability $\frac1k$ of being drawn exactly once. To see this, focus on the $k$ cards that had not yet been drawn when this card was drawn. In the remaining draws, each of the $k$ has the same probability of being drawn last of the $k$, so this probability is $\frac1k$. The card $c_k$ will not be drawn again if and only if it would have been the last of the $k$ to be drawn.

Comment: How can we prove it by calculating $\mathbb{E}(X)$ directly?

Comment: @C.B: Depends on what you mean by "directly"?

Comment: I mean using formula of $\mathbb{E}(X)$ instead of explaining

Comment: @C.B: Well, if you prefer formulas, $\mathbb E(X)=\mathbb E(\sum_kX_k)=\sum_k\mathbb E(X_k)=\sum_kp_k=\sum_k\frac1k$, where $X_k$ is the number of $k$-th last cards drawn exactly once and $p_k$ is the probability of the $k$-th last card being drawn exactly once. To my mind, that obscures more than it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Intriguing question, that corresponds to many equivalent combinatoric schemes, and which all fall into what is known as "the coupon's collector" problem.
Re. for instance to the paper:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304229v1

which contains an exhaustive examination of some particular cases, including that of "coupons drawn only once (singletons)" and the proof that the expected value of x is as you indicated,
which, interestingly, is $1/N$*(expected total No. of draws).