# Expected value of balls observed only once

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

There are $N$ balls in an urn labeled in $\{1,2,3,\dots,N\}$. In each step we choose one ball randomly and observe its label and then put it back to the urn. We continue these observations until observing all of $N$ labels. Calculate the expected value of number of balls observed only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar question has been asked recently.

The answer is $1+1/2+ \dots+1/N$.

Try to show that the k-th last ball has $1/k$ probability of being drawn exactly once. For more details, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704998/expected-number-of-cards-drawn-exactly-once-with-replacement).